# Автоматически открыть список AutoComplete в TextBox

Tags: winapi, winforms, c#

Есть TextBox с неким списком AutoComplete, который присваивается в процессе ввода текста (через AutoCompleteCustomSource). Проблема заключается в том, что при присвоении списка, он не показывается автоматически - показ проходит только при вводе данных с клавиатуры

Необходимо открыть данный список программно.
По сути нужно послать определенное сообщение textbox-у, в голову сразу пришел вариант с `WM_KEYDOWN`, но это решение мне не очень нравится. По сути нужно что-то вроде `CB_SHOWDROPDOWN` для combobox-a, но для textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня есть web-проект, где я использовал библиотеку autocomplete реализованную на javascript. Вообще не важно какой язык, суть одна.
Мне необходимо было создать кнопку, нажимая на которую, мы открываем autocomplete список.
Я возился с этим достаточно, и в итоге все же решился на имитировании события keydown, правда на javascript еще пришлось сделать предварительно фокус на input'e.
Этим я хочу сказать, что не важно каким путем реализовывать в нашем случае эту фишку. Можно и подумать, я в C# начинающий, но по своему опыту сказал все что сделал. Главное что бы результат не отличался от задуманного, ни скоростью, ни качеством. И можно иногда не заморачиваться на мелочах вроде этой, и не тратить бесценного времени. А если решение будет когда нибудь правильнее - успеть переделать (если уж надо) можно всегда.

Answer (score 0):

ImLoaD, спасибо за ответ,

Вообще, в моем случае приоритетней было не столько автоматически показывать, сколько обновлять список autocomplete так, чтобы это выглядело как можно приличнее. (без мерцаний итд.)

Это я реализовал с использованием интерфейсов IAutoComplete и IAutoCompleteDropDown. Кому интересно, могу выложить код.

а автоматическое открытие это просто уже дополнительная фишка) я поэтому и решил спросить, на случай, если кто-то сталкивался. сам не стал этой темой забиваться